# Throwing error in comparing preceding element

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<body>
  <para>
      <phrase>[1.001]</phrase> Arrest is for the pu</para>
    <para>
      <phrase>[1.002]</phrase> Brandon J said in 
    </para>
    <para>
      <phrase>[1.001]</phrase> Singapore used to be and is still
    </para>
</body>
```

And the below XSLT

```
 <xsl:template name="para" match="para">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>
        <div>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./@align">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>para align-</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./@align"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>para</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template name="phrase" match="phrase">
        <span class="phrase">
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\[([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\]">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="preceding::phrase[contains(., current())]">
                            <a name="{concat('CP',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'0'),'-',format-number(number(regex-group(2)),'000'))}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </a>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <a name="{concat('P',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'0'),'-',format-number(number(regex-group(2)),'000'))}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </a>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <a name="{concat('P',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'0'),'-',format-number(number(regex-group(2)),'000'))}">
</a>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
```

Here I'm trying to match the `phrase` with any of the `preceding phrase`, and it is giving me the below error.

```
Error on line 41 
  XPTY0020: Required item type of the context item for the preceding axis is node();
  supplied value has item type xs:string
```

Here i'm unable to understand what is `XPTY:0020`, and why does this error occur.

please let me know how can i fix it.
Here is the [working Demo](http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtk/3)
Thanks

Comment: You can't test for a preceding node because you are under a matching-substring (which is an xs:string). Revise your code to perform the test first then do the analysis of the string thereafter.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is inside `xsl:analyze-string` the context node has changed to an atomic type(`xs:string`), and you are using preceding axis on an `xs:string` item, which is definitely wrong. To correct it, you can use a variable(or a sequence) before `xsl:analyze-string` and store the `preceding::phrase`'s value in it, and use the variable in `xsl:analyze-string` instead of using the preceding axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a variable:

```
   <xsl:template name="phrase" match="phrase">
    <xsl:variable name="this-phrase" select="."/>
    <span class="phrase">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\[([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\]">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$this-phrase/preceding::phrase[contains(., current())]">
```

Obviously the use of `current()` might also be not what you want, depending on which value you want to compare.